# Different portrait and landscape autolayout constraints: where to set them when the device is firstly in landscape?

Tags: ios, autolayout, orientation, nslayoutconstraint

I have set the `NSLayoutConstraint` as `IBOutlet`, and the values I've set in the `storyboard` and `IB` is for portrait orientation. When I run the app in portrait orientation and then I rotate the device to landscape, I manage the constraints updates. But when I run the app being the device already in landscape, the constraints have the values for portrait.

Where should I check the current orientation of the device when the view controller is loaded and the view shown, and set the appropriate constraints according to such orientation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can initially keep a condition in viewDidLoad method

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])){
    // Apply Portrait Constraints
}
else{
    // Apply Landscape Constraints
}
```

later when the user changes orientation you can check in below method and apply the same condition

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)){
          // Apply Portrait Constraints
    }
    else{
          // Apply Landscape Constraints
    }
}
```